# Jenkins Job-Description parse via email

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, dsl, devops

How can i parse the job description daily every day via email.

for example:
[image]

I know there a way using DSL/Groovy.

Thank you for you comments and help, please assist.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the job, you can get the description with this code:

```
job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('nameOfJob')
job.builds.each { j -> println j.description }
```

If you want this for all the jobs, you can loop through all the Jenkins jobs:

```
Jenkins.instance.items.each { j ->
  job.builds.each { b -> println "$j.fullName $b.description" }
}
```

For email, you'd want this in a Jenkins job that you run daily on a timer and does this as a SystemGroovy step.